# How to change display brightness in IOS according to device angle ?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to change the brightness of display according to the angle of the device in iOS. When device is in our eye level or bit lower is correct. But when it's getting more lover, we need to look down or lean down.

No matter what is the application running, we have to check the angle of the device and dim it.  When it come to a normal angle, we have to make make it normal brightness. So we have to run this as a service.

Is this possible ? I think my idea is understandable to anyone. Please help me. I developed this for Android and now I want to know this is possible in iOS. Please help me guys. 
(Check the gif below to get an idea what I need to do.)

[image]

Comment: "No matter what is the application running, ": That's gonna be hard. You shouldn't be allowed to do so.

Comment: @Larme Is this impossible ? Can't we run this as a service in phone ? We don't need to identify any apps . This service need to run in the system always. That's it. can't we add this into system services ?

Comment: There are no "system services". The phone belongs to the user, not you.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.

Here's the apple doc

> Brightness changes made by an app remain in effect until the device is locked, regardless of whether the app is closed. The system brightness (which the user can set in Settings or Control Center) is restored the next time the display is turned on.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617830-brightness

Answer (score 0):

> No matter what is the application running, we have to check the angle of the device and dim it.

You can't. If some other application is running, *your* application is *not* running. Your app is suspended (frozen) or terminated. Either way, no code of yours runs. You can't check *anything*.